# using SHVC video encoder

Tags: video-streaming, codec, scalable

I am trying to generate an SHVC video stream using the reference software [SHM12.3](https://hevc.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_SHVCSoftware/). The repository has the source files so I was able to compile and generate the executables. The problem now is with the parameters that I have to pass to the encoder.

The documentation provided with the reference software contains a quick start guide to use the encoder, which mentions a sample command to run:

```
./targetBitrates.sh -q 22 -o "~/myOutputDirectory/" -ci ldHE BQSquare_416x240_60 -tb "5000 34241 6541" -ca '-e ~/bin/TAppEncoder.exe -cd ~/cfg/'
```

This gives me an error "Unexpected exit status from encodeCommand.sh" although I have created all the required directories and I have all the executables that are required by the shell script targetBitrates.sh. Did anyone else try with SHM12.3 or even any previous version and succeeded to encode a video sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully encode by compiling the linux source file to generate some executables, including "TAppEncoderStatic".

```
./TAppEncoderStatic -c ~/cfg/encoder_randomaccess_scalable.cfg -c ~/cfg/per-sequence-svc/bbb_180-2x.cfg -i0 ~/inputVideos/bbb_180p24.yuv
```

The problem before was that I did not have the test sequence "BQSquare_416x240.yuv", so I tried with my own video sequence and it worked after tweaking the configuration parameters.